# multiprocessing pool.map not processing list in order

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have this script to process some urls in parallel:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

list_of_urls = []

for i in range(1,1000):
    list_of_urls.append('http://example.com/page=' + str(i))

def process_url(url):
    page_processed = url.split('=')[1]
    print 'Processing page %s'% page_processed
    time.sleep(5)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(process_url, list_of_urls)
```

The list is ordered, but when I run it, the script doesn't pick urls from list in order:

```
Processing page 1
Processing page 64
Processing page 127
Processing page 190
Processing page 65
Processing page 2
Processing page 128
Processing page 191
```

Instead, I would like it to process page 1,2,3,4 at first, then continue following the order in the list. Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to split up the task across multiple cores but still run it sequentially? Or is what you want an output list of the processed urls in the correct order. Your question suggests the first.

Comment: The first one. Like you would do in a download manager where you set "max parallel downloads" but they still run in order. I want to process 4 urls at time, example: start with 1, 2, 3, 4. If 3 finishes and 1, 2, 4 are still running, start the 5th (http://example.com/page=5)

Comment: But if your worker function has a return value, the order of the resulting list of return values corresponds to the order of the list of input parameters. Even if the worker functions are processed unordered.

Comment: @elcombato The point you are making is important for newbies in python multiprocessing (like me!). Otherwise the question and the accepted answer is a little bit confusing for not so experienced programmers. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do not pass argument `chunksize`, then `map` will calculate chunks using this algorithm:

```py
chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
if extra:
   chunksize += 1
```

It's cutting your iterable into task_batches and running it on separate processes. That is why it's not in order. The solution is to declare the chunk size equal to 1.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

list_test = range(10)

def process(task):
    print "task:", task
    time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
pool.map(process, list_test, chunksize=1)

task: 0
task: 1
task: 2
task: 3
task: 4
task: 5
task: 6
task: 7
task: 8
task: 9
```

Comment: Note that in most cases, `chunksize=1` will severely hamper performance.

Comment: @BallpointBen Do you have more information on the performance issue with chunksize=1?

Comment: @user1541269 Processes need to synchronize. Optimally if your `chunksize * workers <= jobs` then each worker get and report result once. It means jobs are assigned 'at start' but we lose guarantee of the order.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing is an asynchronous operation, meaning it is by definition non-sequential. Threads (or in python's case processes) pull urls from your list, and there is no guarantee which process will finish first. So url 1 might begin processing before url 64, but because of randomness in network I/O for example, url 64 might finish first.

Ask yourself if you truly need to perform these operations in order, first. If the answer is yes, your best bet is to perform a blocking step- one that forces all parallel computations to complete first, and then sort that completed result.

So if your list of urls is very large, and you want some element of order yet still take advantage of parallelization, you can chunk your list, and then sequentially run each chunk through your parallel logic above.